# jQuery UI Slider: handles with connected input fileds

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I figured out how to have the input fields follow the slide handles once the users moves them. And when typing a value into the field, the slide handle moves to the correct spot on the slider bar, but the input field does not.

```
<input id="min" type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="1.0" />
<input id="max" type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="1" value="4.5" />
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/khds120/qaU7K/

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input change function to:

```
$("input.sliderValue").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    var handle = $(this).attr('id') == 'min' ? 0 : 1;
    $(this).position({
        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center bottom',
        of: $('a.ui-slider-handle:eq(' + handle + ')'),
        offset: "0, -54"
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qaU7K/1/)**

When you change an input, this checks to see the ID of which one you changed, and then moves its position on top of the appropriate handle.

Comment: Don't forget to either upvote this answer if you feel that it helped you and/or select it as the accepted answer.